# How to tell if an int has been changed

Tags: java

I want to know how to tell if an int has been changed (during the program).
Like with an if statement.

```
int i = 2;
int a = 1;

while(1 < 2) {
if(i % 100 == 0) i++;
}

if(i //Then checks if it changed) {
   System.out.println("Changed :D");
}
```

Is there a way to tell if the variable i is changed DURING the program?

Comment: `while(1 < 2)`, smells bad...

Comment: Im guessing you are looking for `if((a % 100) == 0) i++; ... a++;` to increase `i` everytime `a` goes up 100 times?

Comment: If you really want that while loop to repeat indefinitely, then do `while (true) { //...` and provide a break statement somewhere inside its block to stop it. `while (1 < 2)` is quite strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int i = 0;

boolean valueChanged = false;

while(some good condition) {
    if (i % 100 == 0) {
        i++;
        valueChanged = true;
    }
}

if(valueChanged) {
   System.out.println("Changed :D");
}
```

Comment: `if (!valueChanged)` is redundant.  Just `valueChanged = true;` is good enough unless you want to add something else to be done the first time it becomes `true`.

Comment: Thanks ajb. I thought setting 'valueChanged = true;' would be redundant. :)

Comment: I can see that setting it to `true` if it's already `true` could be seen as redundant.  But adding a check doesn't add anything in terms of readability, and it slows things down.  It would be different if setting it to `true` required the program to access the Internet and store the variable value on a remote computer or something.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Since this is Java, are these variables data members of a class? In that case give them `private` access and provide getters and setters. Your setter can notify you if you so desire.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the original value of i in a separate variable and compare i to that?

Comment: What if the if statement was inside a loop.

Comment: ...I don't know, what if? What did you try? An if statement inside a loop isn't much different from an if statement outside of a loop.

Comment: I mean that the variables will be changing constantly.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you're asking, but my original suggestion stands. Keep track of the "original" value of i, whatever or whenever that is, and compare it to i when you want to know whether it has changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Your int variable
int i = 0;
// A scratch variable
int prev_value_of_i = i;

// Call this code to check whether i has changed since last call
if(i != prev_value_of_i) {
    System.out.println("Changed :D");
    prev_value_of_i = i;
}
```

Comment: please don't use words like "below", since StackOverflow likes to change the order of answers.

Answer (score 0):

This seems redundant, since the programmer should know when and where values are stored. If you don't, maybe step through with a debugger? @shoover's answer is the most flexible, handling however many unexpected times you might change the value without requiring adding lines of code inside your infinite loop.

```
class TalkativeInt{
     private int x;
     TalkativeInteger(int x){
          this.x = x;
     }
     public void set(int a){
         System.out.println("Changed!!   "+x+" to "+a);
         x = a;
     }
     public int get(){
         //System.out.println("Accessed - that tickles");
         return x;
     }

}
```